# Rearrange an array so that when written in a space where elements wraps below, it preserves a snake-like order

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, algorithm, sorting

I have an array

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

When it's written in a confined space where elements are forced to wrap, it get's divided into two columns

```
1 2 → ↙
3 4 → ↙
5 6 →
```

But I want to rearrange the array like this

```
1 2 → ↓
6 3   ↓
5 4 ↑ ←
```

And so, get that order as if read like a normal array

```
1 2 6 3 5 4
```

How I know that the array is wraped is by position offsets of each element, like `1` & `2` have same top-offset, and `3` & `4` have some ~10+ more top-offset from `1` & `2`.

The array is an angular $scope object and the elements are created from it inside an ng-repeat directive

So I get the offsets by `$element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom`.

If I could get that order (126354) I would be able to sort the angular array in that order which would make my elements in ng-repeat display in a snake-like manner.

Is there a way to get the (126354) order somehow, based on the offsets of the elements and rearrange the original array in that order?

PS: The number of columns and length of array is arbitrary. In this example there are two columns (3x2), but if it were a 5 length array in 2x3 it would be like this

```
1 2 3
5 4
```

```
1 2 3 5 4
```

Comment: You're on the wrong site. This should be posted here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Benubird No, it does not belong there. Code Golf is for programming contests and programming puzzles, not for general programming questions.

Comment: @ProgramFOX This is a programming puzzle. OP should either extract their programming question from it and just ask that, or post the full puzzle there. As it stands, it's not clear what they are actually asking.

Comment: @Benubird This is not a "puzzle", this is a programming question. The OP has a specific problem to solve. If it is unclear then flag/close it as such.

Comment: This is quite unclear to me. You want the answer to apply to arbitrary-length array, with a spiral-to-the-center order?

Comment: @user189 yes! Also arbitrary length of columns (/spiral) too, which should be inferred from the original offsets of the elements. (in my example it's 2x3, it could have been 3x2)